# Stop form Submitting event propagation in Umbraco backoffice

Tags: angularjs, umbraco

I have custom plugin for Umbraco, which perform additional validation. I tried to call preventDefault of event object, but it don't stop form submitting.

```
$scope.$on("formSubmitting", function(ev, args) {

ev.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.

`preventDefault` prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

Let's say you have

```
$scope.$on("formSubmitting", function(ev, args) {

ev.stopPropagation();
```

**MSDN:**

- [`event.cancelBubble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533545(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [`event.preventDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975460(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [`event.returnValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534372(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [`event.stopPropagation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975462(v=vs.85).aspx)

**MDN:**

- [`event.cancelBubble`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.cancelBubble)
- [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [`event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation)

For IE9 and FF you can just use preventDefault & stopPropagation.

To support IE8 and lower replace `stopPropagation` with `cancelBubble` and replace `preventDefault` with `returnValue`

Comment: There is no "stopPropagation" function in event object, I think because this is some special umbraco event.

Comment: it can be bro. have any stopPropagation method to umbraco? Try to find that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Umbraco there is a `prevent-default` directive. I have used this on anchor elements but not forms, but it might work on forms too!

Usage:

```
<form prevent-default>
    ...
</form>
```